# Test for convergence $\sum_{n\ge1}a^{1+1/2+\cdots+1/n}, a>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Test for convergence 
$$\sum_{n\ge1}a^{1+1/2+\cdots+1/n}, a>0$$
What would you suggest me to do here? If you have some nice proofs and want
to share them then I'll reward them with upvotes.  Thanks!

Comment: As a first step, notice that the sum in the exponent is close to $\ln n$, so the terms you're adding are approximately $a^{\ln n}=e^{(\ln a)(\ln n)}=n^{\ln a}$.  You probably know (or can look up) which values of $\ln a$ make that series converge.  Finally (the hard work) make sure that replacing $1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n$ with $\ln n$ didn't make enough difference to affect the convergence.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: maybe for the hard part we may employ the mean value theorem. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$1 + 1/2 + \ldots + 1/n = \ln(n) +O(1)$, and $a^{\ln(n)} = e^{\ln(a) \ln(n)} = n^{\ln(a)}$.
So it will converge for $\ln(a) < -1$ (i.e. $a < 1/e$) and diverge for $a \ge 1/e$.

Comment: robert israel :whats O(1) and how copmute $1 + 1/2 + \ldots + 1/n$

Comment: $O(1)$ means bounded as $n \to \infty$.  To get bounds on that sum, you can compare it to an integral.